# R shiny: selectInput - pieces of javascript appear in UI

Tags: r, shiny

The goal is to display a list of selectInput inputs. The list is displayed correctly but next to the name of every separate input menu ('a', 'b', 'c' in this example) the following string is displayed: 'div form-group shiny-input-container'. I would greatly appreciate a hint why this is happening!

Screenshot:

[image]

**ui.R**

```
shinyUI(
  htmlOutput("tabs")
)
```

**server.R**

```
shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

output$tabs<-renderUI({
    navbarPage("MyApp",tabPanel("Tab",htmlOutput("myoutput")))
})

output$myoutput<-renderUI({ 
  datavector<-c('one','two','three')  
  outputlist<-list()  
  for (i in 1:3) {
    output<-selectInput(paste("selection",i,sep=""), c('a','b','c')[i], 
                        c("one"=1,"two"=2,"three"=3),
                        selected=datavector[i])
    outputlist<-append(outputlist,output)
  }  
  outputlist
})
})
```

Thanks in advance!

Bogdan

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hello it's because `append` doesn't handle list element the way you want, use `list` instead :

```
output$myoutput<-renderUI({ 
  datavector<-c('one','two','three')  
  outputlist<-list()  
  for (i in 1:3) {
    output<-selectInput(paste("selection",i,sep=""), c('a','b','c')[i], 
                        c("one"=1,"two"=2,"three"=3),
                        selected = datavector[i])
    outputlist <- list(outputlist, output)
  }  
  outputlist
})
```

Nonetheless I will recommend you to use `lapply`, it's much clearier :

```
output$myoutput<-renderUI({ 
    datavector<-c('one','two','three')  
    lapply(X = 1:3, FUN = function(i) {
      selectInput(paste("selection",i,sep=""), c('a','b','c')[i], 
                  c("one"=1,"two"=2,"three"=3),
                  selected=i)
    })
  })
```

Note : I replaced `selected = datavector[i]` by `selected = i` because of :

```
'selected' must be the values instead of names of 'choices' for the input 'selection'
```